# How to avoid putting the sending email address in Swift_Message in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

Here I use swift_message to send messages with Symfony, and I've set my swift_mailer. But in the setFrom (""), I entered the email address in hard, which allows me to send the mails, but I would like to know if there is another way to inject this address, so that it n does not appear in my code.

**Parameters.yml**

```
  parameters:
database_driver: pdo_mysql
database_host: localhost
database_port: 3306
database_name: doctrax
database_user: root
database_password: null
mailer_transport: gmail         
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: minitest@gmail.com
mailer_password: "785468961A;"
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
mailer_auth_mode: login
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_port: 465
```

**Controller**

```
   $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Email de Confirmaton'))
        ->setFrom("minitest@gmail.com")
        ->setTo($patient->getUser()->getUsername())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'Emails/confirmation.html.twig',
                array('name' => 'mam')
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);
```

Now I would like to know if there is another way to inject the email address of the sender, and that his email does not appear in the code at the setFrom.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to don't share sensible data on your issue like password

Comment: Hi @Matteo, thanks, but i've changed the data before sharing

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [doc here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html), you could add the `sender_address` as example:

```
mailer_user: [USERNAME]
mailer_password: [PASSWORD]
mailer_port: 465
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_sender_address: noreply@mydomain.com
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi @Matteo, the send address I use is the one that is defined in mailer_user.But in my controller at the setFrom, I do not want to enter this address there hard

Comment: Maybe this will also help? `setFrom($this->getParameter('mailer_sender_address'))`

Comment: @Matteo, I've tried your recommendation, but i have no error but email is not sending.